# Save last 4 seconds of typing in python

Tags: python, text, save

I have a very strange question. Is it possible for a python programme to save the last 4 seconds of what you type. For example, say I'm typing and there's a trigger (which could be anything like a decrease in frame rate or a letter being pressed a certain amount of times) python would save the last 4 seconds worth of typing I did into a text file. It may be difficult to understand what I mean so ask as many questions as you want.

Comment: what you are looking for is a keylogger. try googling `python keylogger`

Comment: @Fire That isn't the bit I'm stuck on, the bit that I am finding difficult is the "saving last 4 seconds" bit.

Comment: well a keylogger logs every keystroke while it is running. therefore, you could potentially create a keylogger that reacts to a certain combination of keys and save the next 4 seconds of logging in a file. if this is for your own usage i suggest you modify something already existing

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have a go.

Comment: @Fire Thanks for the idea, I bodged it up and it works!
Edit: I used pyhook if you were interested.